# Need Nginx Expert (Wordpress plugin issue)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

i'm running a wordpress website on nginx, all working like a charm except with one of my plugin = [Adaptive Images for WordPress](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/adaptive-images/). (This plugin serve scaled image).

The owner of this plugin said that, add this to location but it's don't works.

```
location / {
rewrite \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ /wp-content/plugins/adaptive-images/adaptive-images-script.php;
}
```

Have also tried this:

```
location ~ /wp-content/(themes|uploads) {
     rewrite \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ /wp-content/plugins/adaptive-images/adaptive-images-script.php;
}
```

and this:

```
location ~ /wp-content/(themes|uploads) {
rewrite \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ /wp-content/plugins/adaptive-images/adaptive-images-script.php;
```

}

Nothing worked!

Here is my nginx config: https://github.com/stonedb00/stonedb/blob/master/nginxconf

So i need an nginx expert to give me the correct rewrite config and resolve it !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that all of your image requests are processed by nginx with this `location` block:

```
location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires               60d;
    log_not_found         off;
}
```

Since you are going to process all image requests with the plugin, try the following config:

```
location / {
    rewrite \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ /wp-content/plugins/adaptive-images/adaptive-images-script.php last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# other locations here
...

location ~* .(js|css|ico)$ {
    expires               60d;
    log_not_found         off;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Ivan, i have updated my configuration with your instructions.
Here is my 'new conf': https://github.com/stonedb00/stonedb/blob/master/newnginxconf 

But still don't working, image are not generated.

If you have another suggestion...

Comment: This plugin generate files in "wp-content/cache/adaptive-images", and this directory still empty.

But where is strange, when i go to 

https://sampledomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sample-image-1.jpg?debug=true 

it showing 

'You are viewing this page instead of the image you requested. This is part of the debugging capabilities of the Adaptive Images plugin. Seeing this means the plugin is running alright...'

I think the issue with nginx conf is resolved, i'll contact the plugin owner to solve this another issue.

Again, thanks a lot Ivan !

Comment: You can try to force image generation with the links like this: www.sampledomain.com/wp-content/<path-to-image>/picture.png?resolution=640,1 (use any real image path, any of resolutions you set on your admin page)

Comment: Plugin developer is not to blame for not being able to foresee every special case like using `location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { ... }` for increasing caching time for some file types :) The only thing that needed to be corrected in his docs is to use `last` flag with the `rewrite` directive.